# Why is Ubuntu One syncing so slow?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

I'd like to use Ubuntu One to sync some important files that I use frequently across several machines. I have ubuntu one set up correctly (or so it appears), yet when I add the folder, it took about 15 minutes to upload a single 5kb readme file. There is a notification that says it is transferring X and #### other files, and I guess it is, but it is doing so painfully slowly. My connection is not slow; there seems to be no reason for the speed to be so poor. I've checked the settings and I don't have the bandwidth limiter on either.

Does anyone else have this problem? I can't image anyone using this service or paying for it for that matter if it were so slow. What can I do about it?

Also, I'm on 11.10 64bit

Answer (score 2):

We've been having issues with our file synchronizing servers. They're on their way to being resolved; you should find the service better already, with more improvements to come (today it'll still be slow during peak hours).