# UbuntuOne syncing really slow

Tags: ubuntu-one

I had my Documents folder synced in 11.10. I erased my harddisk before installing 12.04. I then set up U1 the same way and waited to get my files transferred to my hdd. It's really slow and I neither see some kind of progress bar or percentage shown nor do I know the exact speed of the download. I don't have a slow connection here. Is this normal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Ubuntu One syncing so slow?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94270/why-is-ubuntu-one-syncing-so-slow)

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-client/+bug/991250

In the list of the duplicates you can read one of them that is mine. In fact there is a problem with the overwhelming net's traffic in these days. Be patient.

Comment: It's alright. My mistake that I used U1 for backup purposes. Should have used my external hdd.